# Getting the back button to go to the Launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, splash-screen

I have a `SplashActivity` which opens up when I first open the app,this leads to the app's `MainActvity` I would like to program the back button so that the it goes to the launcher instead of the SplashActivity.

```
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        
        //what goes here??
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Or do I get this by setting the right flag when launching the `MainActivity` from `SplashActivity`.

## EDIT:

I figured one part of the answer,to ensure that SplashActivity is never launched,I use

```
  Intent i=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
```

I have three other `Activities` which redirect to MainActivity,I want to provide a consistent behaviour where I can redirect back from the `MainActivity` to the launcher everytime.

## EDIT2

`MainActivity--->Camera/Gallery--->ImagePreview--->ScannedResults-->image delete dialog-->MainActivity`

I press `back` from the `MainActivity` it cannot go back to `ScannedResults`,`Camera` or `ImagePreview` as there is a possibility that the user deleted the image from the `ImagePreview` as well.

Comment: Why don't you use Intent

Comment: @Gunaseelan check out my clarification,I have edited the post

Comment: Try after removing `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);` this line.

Comment: @user2309862 i think that EDIT2 is another question.

Comment: It is precisely a description of why I want what I want.I would like my MainActivity to not launch another another Activity when the back button is pressed,instead i would like it to destroy the activity/leave the app in the backstack and open the Launcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close the application u can use

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
         finish();
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

But if you just want to hide the application (still running on background) you can use

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
         moveTaskToBack(true);
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Hopefully it will help..

Answer (score 1):

In essence then, you want to go to Launcher (I'm assuming it's NOT the main activity, tell if otherwise) from every activity. In that case, whenever you start any activity with an Intent, call finish() right after, eg.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WhateverActivityYouWantToCall.class);
startActivity(intent)

//call finish() to end current activity
finish();
```

EDIT: That being said, if you want this to happen on Back button press, you can override onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent quit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    quit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    quit.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(quit);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Activities in my app redirect to the MainActivity when back button is pressed.I would like the MainActivity to redirect to the launcher instead of redirecting to another Activity at all times.In my app,navigating backwards is meaningless and navigation back from the MainActivity to another Activity might reveal non-existent data.

Answer (score 1):

If you exclude Activity from recents, by using `android:excludeFromRecents` it will also not be on back stack, so user will not be able to manually get back to it neither with BACK button, nor from recents. Just edit your Manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" />
```

**EDIT**

you can always get rid of multiple activities and switch to Fragments, so you will have only one activity, always visible in recents, but still can have ie. SplashFragment out if back stack

Comment: I have edited my post to provide full disclosure,it is just that I am passing the path of an Image around when I launch the Activity,this image could be deleted at any of the two points I specified,going back and trying to do something with the image and later finding out that the image does not exist is not fair to the user.

Comment: I found that by using `android:excludeFromRecents` instead of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` along with `moveTaskToBack(true)` I found that my app would not show up in the recent apps drawer.I think the Quora app has similar issues where it disappears from the recent apps and reappears later,sometimes.

Comment: so you want me to create an Activity with a FrameLayout embedded within something else...keep adding/removing fragments as required cool idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having only 2 activity SplashActivity and MainActivity. In that case, just after you start MainActivity from SplashActivity call finish() and override onBackPressed() in MainActivity and call finish().

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your SplashActivity on your manifest:

```
<activity
android:name=".SplashActivity"
android:noHistory="true" >
```

After that, you can forget of i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); on your code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
SplashActivity.finish();
```